# how to pass file names to list in python in a certain format?

Tags: ubuntu, python, audio

I am following this tutorial : http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/amsehili/audio-segmentation-by-classification-tutorial/blob/master/multiclass_audio_segmentation.ipynb
In block [8] of tutorial there is:

```
train_data = {}
train_data["silence"] = ["silence_1.wav", "silence_2.wav",   "silence_3.wav"]  
train_data["speech"]  = ["speech_1.wav", "speech_2.wav", "speech_3.wav", "speech_4.wav", "speech_5.wav"]
```

i.e we are passing names of the .wav files contained in one folder;

Instead of silence/speech I want to train/pass it my own music segments. So , I chopped up one music bit into smaller pieces using :

```
ffmpeg -i hm1.mp3 -c copy -map 0 -segment_time 1 -f segment hm1_%03d.mp3
```

This generated 120 `1 second long mp3 chunks` of the original file.
I saved the filenames of these 1 second chunks using

```
ls >filenames.txt
```

It is impossible to type a 120 `"abc.wav" ,` what is the best way to pass all 120+ file names of the generated music bits in the format as shown above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get Python to build the list?

```
$ python3
Python 3.5.2 (default, Nov 23 2017, 16:37:01)
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> a = ["hm1_{:03d}.mp3".format(i) for i in range(120)]
>>> a
['hm1_000.mp3', 'hm1_001.mp3', 'hm1_002.mp3', 'hm1_003.mp3', 'hm1_004.mp3', 'hm1_005.mp3', 'hm1_006.mp3', 'hm1_007.mp3', 'hm1_008.mp3', 'hm1_009.mp3', 'hm1_010.mp3', 'hm1_011.mp3', 'hm1_012.mp3', 'hm1_013.mp3', 'hm1_014.mp3', 'hm1_015.mp3', 'hm1_016.mp3', 'hm1_017.mp3', 'hm1_018.mp3', 'hm1_019.mp3', 'hm1_020.mp3', 'hm1_021.mp3', 'hm1_022.mp3', 'hm1_023.mp3', 'hm1_024.mp3', 'hm1_025.mp3', 'hm1_026.mp3', 'hm1_027.mp3', 'hm1_028.mp3', 'hm1_029.mp3', 'hm1_030.mp3', 'hm1_031.mp3', 'hm1_032.mp3', 'hm1_033.mp3', 'hm1_034.mp3', 'hm1_035.mp3', 'hm1_036.mp3', 'hm1_037.mp3', 'hm1_038.mp3', 'hm1_039.mp3', 'hm1_040.mp3', 'hm1_041.mp3', 'hm1_042.mp3', 'hm1_043.mp3', 'hm1_044.mp3', 'hm1_045.mp3', 'hm1_046.mp3', 'hm1_047.mp3', 'hm1_048.mp3', 'hm1_049.mp3', 'hm1_050.mp3', 'hm1_051.mp3', 'hm1_052.mp3', 'hm1_053.mp3', 'hm1_054.mp3', 'hm1_055.mp3', 'hm1_056.mp3', 'hm1_057.mp3', 'hm1_058.mp3', 'hm1_059.mp3', 'hm1_060.mp3', 'hm1_061.mp3', 'hm1_062.mp3', 'hm1_063.mp3', 'hm1_064.mp3', 'hm1_065.mp3', 'hm1_066.mp3', 'hm1_067.mp3', 'hm1_068.mp3', 'hm1_069.mp3', 'hm1_070.mp3', 'hm1_071.mp3', 'hm1_072.mp3', 'hm1_073.mp3', 'hm1_074.mp3', 'hm1_075.mp3', 'hm1_076.mp3', 'hm1_077.mp3', 'hm1_078.mp3', 'hm1_079.mp3', 'hm1_080.mp3', 'hm1_081.mp3', 'hm1_082.mp3', 'hm1_083.mp3', 'hm1_084.mp3', 'hm1_085.mp3', 'hm1_086.mp3', 'hm1_087.mp3', 'hm1_088.mp3', 'hm1_089.mp3', 'hm1_090.mp3', 'hm1_091.mp3', 'hm1_092.mp3', 'hm1_093.mp3', 'hm1_094.mp3', 'hm1_095.mp3', 'hm1_096.mp3', 'hm1_097.mp3', 'hm1_098.mp3', 'hm1_099.mp3', 'hm1_100.mp3', 'hm1_101.mp3', 'hm1_102.mp3', 'hm1_103.mp3', 'hm1_104.mp3', 'hm1_105.mp3', 'hm1_106.mp3', 'hm1_107.mp3', 'hm1_108.mp3', 'hm1_109.mp3', 'hm1_110.mp3', 'hm1_111.mp3', 'hm1_112.mp3', 'hm1_113.mp3', 'hm1_114.mp3', 'hm1_115.mp3', 'hm1_116.mp3', 'hm1_117.mp3', 'hm1_118.mp3', 'hm1_119.mp3']
```

Comment: thanks for the quick and amazingly crisp solution. 
So do the " double quotes" not matter?
i.e here `train_data["silence"] = ["silence_1.wav", "silence_2.wav",   "silence_3.wav"]  `
 author passes everything in double quotes.

would i just do `train_data["silence"]=a`  is there anyway to modify solution so that it matches the same exact format as in the tutotial?

Comment: @kRazzyR The only quotes that behave differently in Python are triple quotes `""" .... """`/`''' ... '''`. `" "` and `' '` aren't treated differently: https://stackoverflow.com/a/144163/2072269

Comment: @kRazzyR also, as you can see, I used `" "` in my command, but the output contained `' '`. Python doesn't care.

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation and the elegant solution. I am new to python and have much to learn on this journey.